# Function using vectors in C++

Tags: c++, vector

I have the following C++ function:

```
std::vector<int> findPoss (std::vector<int>& possRow, std::vector<int>& possCol)
{
    std::vector<int> poss;
    for (int a = 0; a < 9; a++)
        for (int b = 0; b < 9; b++)
            if (possRow[a] == possCol[b])
                poss.push_back(possRow[a]);
    return poss;
}
```

Which should take two a vectors, and return a vector containing all elements that were found in both the input vectors.
However, the returning vector always includes 1. For example, if I inputed this:

```
std::vector<int> possRow;
for (int a = 0; a < 9; a++) possRow.push_back(a);
std::vector<int> possCol;
for (int b = 0; b < 9; b += 2) possCol.push_back(b);
findPoss(possow, possCol)
```

It would return this:

```
(0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8)
```

Why is this so?

Also, in my `findPoss` function, there isn't any inbuilt functions that would include both `for` loops in one, is there?

Comment: Why is there that magic `9`? Why not `.size()`?

Comment: Side note: `possRow` and `possCol` should be references-to-*const*-vector if you do not intend to alter them.

Comment: You could write this sudoku solver using integer bitmasks instead of vectors. Then the entire thing would be just one line: `return possRow & possCol`..

Answer (score 4):

```
for (int b = 0; b < 9; b += 2) possCol.push_back(b);
```

will populate `possCol` with `[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]` which is of size `5` while you are using it inside a `for (int b = 0; b < 9; b++)` loop which will cause *undefined behavior*.

I suggest you to use `for (int b = 0; b < possCol.size(); b++)` and `for (int a = 0; a < possRow.size(); a++)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your code `for (int b = 0; b < 9; b += 2) possCol.push_back(b);` produces a vector with five elements but you are looping over possCol nine times, getting garbage memory.
Though it's interesting you received `(0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8)` as a result.

Modifying that for loop to read `for (int b = 0; b < possCol.size(); b += 2)` in your findposs function will return {0, 2, 4, 6, 8} as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Range-based for loops make this a whole lot cleaner:

```
std::vector<int> findPoss (const std::vector<int>& possRow, const std::vector<int>& possCol)
{
    std::vector<int> poss;
    for (int row : possRow)
        for (int col : possCol)
            if (row == col)
                poss.push_back(row);
    return poss;
}
```